# How do I optimize my Pinescript script (make it faster and simpler to read)?

Tags: optimization, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a complex Pine Script v5 code that displays a screener for buy/sell signals across different timeframes and pairs.

I am concerned about its performance and resource usage, as it currently loads slowly and consumes significant memory resources.

To optimize the script, I am seeking suggestions on how to make it load faster and be more memory-efficient while maintaining its functionality and accuracy.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Screener", overlay = true)

import sammie123567858/Indicators/9 as indicator
import jdehorty/KernelFunctions/2 as kernels
import TradingView/ta/5 as ta











////////////
// INPUTS //

u01 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's01')
u02 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's02')
u03 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's03')
u04 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's04')
u05 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's05')
u06 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's06')
u07 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's07')
u08 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's08')
u09 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's09')
u10 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's10')
u11 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's11')
u12 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's12')
u13 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's13')
u14 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's14')
u15 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's15')



s01 = input.symbol('EURUSD', group='Symbols', inline='s01')
s02 = input.symbol('USDJPY', group='Symbols', inline='s02')
s03 = input.symbol('GBPUSD', group='Symbols', inline='s03')
s04 = input.symbol('AUDUSD', group='Symbols', inline='s04')
s05 = input.symbol('USDCHF', group='Symbols', inline='s05')
s06 = input.symbol('USDCAD', group='Symbols', inline='s06')
s07 = input.symbol('NZDUSD', group='Symbols', inline='s07')
s08 = input.symbol('GBPJPY', group='Symbols', inline='s08')
s09 = input.symbol('EURAUD', group='Symbols', inline='s09')
s10 = input.symbol('XAUUSD', group='Symbols', inline='s10')
s11 = input.symbol('EURNZD', group='Symbols', inline='s11')
s12 = input.symbol('AUDGBP', group='Symbols', inline='s12')
s13 = input.symbol('USDAUD', group='Symbols', inline='s13')
s14 = input.symbol('CADNZD', group='Symbols', inline='s14')
s15 = input.symbol('AUDJPY', group='Symbols', inline='s15')


// Display inputs
col_width = input.float(2, title = "Column Width (%)", group = 'Table Theme')
textSize = switch input.string("Auto", "Size", options = ['Auto', 'Tiny', 'Small', 'Normal', 'Large', 'Huge'], group = 'Table Theme')
    "Auto" => size.auto
    "Tiny" => size.tiny
    "Small" => size.small
    "Normal" => size.normal
    "Large" => size.large
    "Huge" => size.huge
location = switch input.string("Top Right", "Table Location",
 options = ['Top Right', 'Top Center', 'Top Left', 'Middle Right', 'Middle Center', 'Middle Left', 'Bottom Right', 'Bottom Center', 'Bottom Left'], group = 'Table Theme')
    "Top Right" => position.top_right
    "Top Center" => position.top_center
    "Top Left" => position.top_left
    "Middle Right" => position.middle_right
    "Middle Center" => position.middle_center
    "Middle Left" => position.middle_left
    "Bottom Right" => position.bottom_right
    "Bottom Center" => position.bottom_center
    "Bottom Left" => position.bottom_left


// timeframes
lowerTF = input.timeframe('1', 'Lower timeframe', group = 'Strategy')
higherTF = input.timeframe('5', 'Higher timeframe', group = 'Strategy')
tpRatio = input.float(1, 'TP Ratio')


//fast Kernel line inputs
float kernelFastWeight = input.float(8, "Rel Weight", 0 , 50, step = 0.2, group = "Fast AO Kernel Settings")
int kernelFastLookback = input.int(5, "Lookback",2 , 500, group = "Fast AO Kernel Settings")
int kernelFastRegressionStart = input.int(25, "Regression Start",2 , 400, group = "Fast AO Kernel Settings")
bool kernelFastSmooth = input.bool(true, "Smooth Line", inline = "Smooth", group = "Fast AO Kernel Settings")
int kernelFastSmoothPeriod = input.int(4, "",2 , 200, inline = "Smooth", group = "Fast AO Kernel Settings")

//slow Kernel line inputs
float kernelSlowWeight = input.float(3, "Rel Weight", 0 , 5, step = 0.2, group = "Slow AO Kernel Settings")
int kernelSlowLookback = input.int(34, "Lookback",2 , 500, group = "Slow AO Kernel Settings")
int kernelSlowRegressionStart = input.int(120, "Regression Start",2 , 400, group = "Slow AO Kernel Settings")
bool kernelSlowSmooth = input.bool(true, "Smooth Line", inline = "Smooth", group = "Slow AO Kernel Settings")
int kernelSlowSmoothPeriod = input.int(40, "",2 , 200, inline = "Smooth", group = "Slow AO Kernel Settings")

// rsi range shift inputs
rsiLengthInput = input.int(14, minval=1, title="RSI Length", group="RSI Settings")
rsiSourceInput = input.source(close, "Source", group="RSI Settings")
bullRangeTop = input.float(80, title="Bull Range Top", tooltip = 'the UPPER price level of the BULLISH range. Default is 80.', group="RSI Settings")
bullRangeBottom = input.float(60, title="Bull Range Bottom", tooltip = 'the LOWER price level of the BULLISH range. Default is 60.', group="RSI Settings")
bearRangeTop = input.float(40, title="Bear Range Top", tooltip = 'the UPPER price level of the BEARISH range. Default is 40.', group="RSI Settings")
bearRangeBottom = input.float(20, title="Bear Range Bottom", tooltip = 'the LOWER price level of the BEARISH range. Default is 20.', group="RSI Settings")





















//////////////////
// CALCULATIONS //

// @function takes in the timeframe and returns its text equivalent
timeframeInText(string tf) =>
    tf


// Get only symbol
only_symbol(s) => 
    array.get(str.split(s, ":"), 1)


id_symbol(s)=>
    switch s
        1  => only_symbol(s01)
        2  => only_symbol(s02)
        3  => only_symbol(s03)
        4  => only_symbol(s04)
        5  => only_symbol(s05)
        6  => only_symbol(s06)
        7  => only_symbol(s07)
        8  => only_symbol(s08)
        9  => only_symbol(s09)
        10 => only_symbol(s10)
        11  => only_symbol(s11)
        12  => only_symbol(s12)
        13  => only_symbol(s13)
        14  => only_symbol(s14)
        15  => only_symbol(s15)
        => na



// kernel ao oscillator indicator (this will be used for the fast kernel, slow kernel & kernel ao oscillator)
kernelFast = kernels.rationalQuadratic(close, kernelFastLookback, kernelFastWeight, kernelFastRegressionStart)
if kernelFastSmooth
    kernelFast := ta.sma(kernelFast, kernelFastSmoothPeriod)
kernelFastRising = ta.rising(kernelFast, 1)
kernelFastColor = kernelFastRising ? #542772 : #df4774

kernelSlow = kernels.rationalQuadratic(close, kernelSlowLookback, kernelSlowWeight, kernelSlowRegressionStart)
if kernelSlowSmooth
    kernelSlow := ta.sma(kernelSlow, kernelSlowSmoothPeriod)
kernelSlowRising = ta.rising(kernelSlow, 1)
kernelSlowColor = kernelSlowRising ? #542772 : #df4774

osc = kernelFast - kernelSlow
diff = osc[1] - osc[2]
isPurple = diff <= 0 ? false : true


fastKernel() =>
    kernelFastColor[1] == #542772 ? 0 : kernelFastColor[1] == #df4774 ? 1 : -1

slowKernel() =>
    kernelSlowColor[1] == #542772 ? 0 : kernelSlowColor[1] == #df4774 ? 1 : -1

kernelAO() =>
    isPurple[1] and osc[1] > 0 ? 0 : not isPurple[1] and osc[1] > 0 ? 1 : not isPurple[1] and osc[1] < 0 ? 2 : isPurple[1] and osc[1] < 0 ? 3 : -1

rsiRangeShift() =>
    rsi = indicator.rsi(rsiSourceInput, rsiLengthInput)
    bull = rsi[1] <= bullRangeTop and rsi[1] >= bullRangeBottom 
    bear = rsi[1] <= bearRangeTop and rsi[1] >= bearRangeBottom 
    neutral = rsi[1] >= bearRangeTop and rsi[1] <= bullRangeBottom 
    bull ? 0 : bear ? 1 : neutral ? 2 : -1

kernelAoSwing() =>
    [swingHigh, swingLow] = indicator.drawSwings(osc, false)
    [swingHigh, swingLow]

kernelAoSwingHigh() =>
    [swingHigh, swingLow] = kernelAoSwing()
    swingHigh

kernelAoSwingLow() =>
    [swingHigh, swingLow] = kernelAoSwing()
    swingLow



screener_func() =>
    [fastKernel(), slowKernel(), kernelAO(), rsiRangeShift(), close[1], kernelAoSwingHigh(), kernelAoSwingLow(), close, high, low]

// Set Up Matrix
screenerMtx = matrix.new<float>(0, 11, na)

screenerFun(numSym, sym, flg, tf) =>
    [fastK, slowK, ao, rangeShift, prevClosePrice, swingHigh, swingLow, currClosePRice, currHigh, currLow] = request.security(sym, tf, screener_func()) 
    if flg 
        arr = array.from(numSym, fastK, slowK, ao, rangeShift, prevClosePrice, swingHigh, swingLow, currClosePRice, currHigh, currLow)
        matrix.add_row(screenerMtx, matrix.rows(screenerMtx), arr)

// Security call
screenerFun(01, s01, u01, lowerTF),  screenerFun(01, s01, u01, higherTF), 
screenerFun(02, s02, u02, lowerTF),  screenerFun(02, s02, u02, higherTF),
screenerFun(03, s03, u03, lowerTF),  screenerFun(03, s03, u03, higherTF),  
screenerFun(04, s04, u04, lowerTF),  screenerFun(04, s04, u04, higherTF),
screenerFun(05, s05, u05, lowerTF),  screenerFun(05, s05, u05, higherTF),
screenerFun(06, s06, u06, lowerTF),  screenerFun(06, s06, u06, higherTF), 
screenerFun(07, s07, u07, lowerTF),  screenerFun(07, s07, u07, higherTF), 
screenerFun(08, s08, u08, lowerTF),  screenerFun(08, s08, u08, higherTF),
screenerFun(09, s09, u09, lowerTF),  screenerFun(09, s09, u09, higherTF),
screenerFun(10, s10, u10, lowerTF),  screenerFun(10, s10, u10, higherTF),
screenerFun(11, s11, u11, lowerTF),  screenerFun(11, s11, u11, higherTF),
screenerFun(12, s12, u12, lowerTF),  screenerFun(12, s12, u12, higherTF),
screenerFun(13, s13, u13, lowerTF),  screenerFun(13, s13, u13, higherTF),
screenerFun(14, s14, u14, lowerTF),  screenerFun(14, s14, u14, higherTF),
screenerFun(15, s15, u15, lowerTF),  screenerFun(15, s15, u15, higherTF)


















///////////
// PLOTS //
tpLineColor = color.new(#4dc251, 0)
slLineColor = color.new(color.red, 0)
lineWidth = 2
entryTime = str.format_time(time, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", timezone = 'Asia/Kolkata')

trade = bool(na)
var counter = 1 //for giving new identifiers to every new trade
string msg = ''
bool check = false
var tradeMtx = matrix.new<float>(41, 5, 1)
var tbl = table.new(location, 8, 41, frame_color=#151715, frame_width=1, border_width=2, border_color=color.new(color.white, 100))


if barstate.islast
    
    // DRAWS TABLE
    table.cell(tbl, 0, 0, 'Sym', width = col_width, text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = #000000, text_color = color.white, text_size = textSize)
    table.cell(tbl, 1, 0, '1', width = col_width, text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = #000000, text_color = color.white, text_size = textSize)
    table.cell(tbl, 2, 0, '2', width = col_width, text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = #000000, text_color = color.white, text_size = textSize)
    table.cell(tbl, 3, 0, '3', width = col_width, text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = #000000, text_color = color.white, text_size = textSize)
    table.cell(tbl, 4, 0, '4', width = col_width, text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = #000000, text_color = color.white, text_size = textSize)
    table.cell(tbl, 5, 0, 'Entry', width = col_width, text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = #000000, text_color = color.white, text_size = textSize)
    table.cell(tbl, 6, 0, 'TP', width = col_width, text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = #000000, text_color = color.white, text_size = textSize)
    table.cell(tbl, 7, 0, 'SL', width = col_width, text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = #000000, text_color = color.white, text_size = textSize)


    if matrix.rows(screenerMtx) > 0
        bool isLowerTF = true
        string txt = '' 
        string tpSlMsg = ''
        for i = 0 to matrix.rows(screenerMtx) - 1

            // GETTING THAT PARTICULAR SYMBOL'S DATA
            // indicator's signals
            fast_kernel_signal =  matrix.get(screenerMtx, i, 1) 
            slow_kernel_signal =  matrix.get(screenerMtx, i, 2) 
            kernel_ao_signal = matrix.get(screenerMtx, i, 3)
            kernel_ao_bearish = kernel_ao_signal == 2 or kernel_ao_signal == 3
            kernel_ao_bullish = kernel_ao_signal == 0 or kernel_ao_signal == 1
            range_shift_signal = matrix.get(screenerMtx, i, 4)

            // indicator's colors
            fast_kernel  = fast_kernel_signal == 1 ? color.red : fast_kernel_signal == 0 ? color.green : #323232 
            slow_kernel  = slow_kernel_signal == 1 ? color.red : slow_kernel_signal == 0 ? color.green : #323232 
            kernel_ao  = kernel_ao_signal == 0 ? #028239 : kernel_ao_signal == 1 ? #00e676 : kernel_ao_signal == 2 ? #a80000 : kernel_ao_signal == 3 ? color.red : #323232 
            range_shift  = range_shift_signal == 0 ? color.green : range_shift_signal == 1 ? color.red : range_shift_signal == 2 ? color.blue : #323232

        


            // checking if trades are getting closed
            symbol = id_symbol(matrix.get(screenerMtx, i, 0))
            timeframeText = timeframeInText(isLowerTF ? lowerTF:higherTF) 
            isEntryOngoing = matrix.get(tradeMtx, i + 1, 0)
            direction = matrix.get(tradeMtx, i + 1, 3)
            currPrice = matrix.get(screenerMtx, i, 8)
            currHigh = matrix.get(screenerMtx, i, 9)
            currLow = matrix.get(screenerMtx, i, 10)
            tradeTp = matrix.get(tradeMtx, i + 1, 1)
            tradeSl = matrix.get(tradeMtx, i + 1, 2)


            // checking if a sell got closed
            if isEntryOngoing == 0 and direction == 1 
                if currPrice >= tradeSl or currHigh >= tradeSl
                    matrix.set(tradeMtx, i + 1, 0, 2)
                    table.cell_set_bgcolor(tbl, 5, i + 1, bgcolor = #323232)
                    table.cell_set_bgcolor(tbl, 6, i + 1, bgcolor = #323232)
                    table.cell(tbl, 7, i + 1, 'Closed at SL\n' + str.tostring(tradeSl), bgcolor = #c8b50a, text_color = #000000, text_size = textSize)
                    tpSlMsg += 'Closed Sell' + '|' + symbol + '|' + timeframeText + '|' + entryTime + '|' + ' at SL\n'
                if currPrice <= tradeTp or currLow <= tradeTp
                    matrix.set(tradeMtx, i + 1, 0, 2)
                    table.cell_set_bgcolor(tbl, 5, i + 1, bgcolor = #323232)
                    table.cell_set_bgcolor(tbl, 7, i + 1, bgcolor = #323232)
                    table.cell(tbl, 6, i + 1, 'Closed at TP\n' + str.tostring(tradeTp), bgcolor = #c8b50a, text_color = #000000, text_size = textSize)
                    tpSlMsg += 'Closed Sell' + '|' + symbol + '|' + timeframeText + '|' + entryTime + '|' + ' at TP\n'
     
            
            // checking if a buy got closed
            if isEntryOngoing == 0 and direction == 0 
                if currPrice <= tradeSl or currLow <= tradeSl
                    matrix.set(tradeMtx, i + 1, 0, 2)
                    table.cell_set_bgcolor(tbl, 5, i + 1, bgcolor = #323232)
                    table.cell_set_bgcolor(tbl, 6, i + 1, bgcolor = #323232)
                    table.cell(tbl, 7, i + 1, 'Closed at SL\n' + str.tostring(tradeSl), bgcolor = #c8b50a, text_color = #000000, text_size = textSize)
                    tpSlMsg += 'Closed Buy' + '|' + symbol + '|' + timeframeText + '|' + entryTime + '|' + ' at SL\n'
                if currPrice >= tradeTp or currHigh >= tradeTp
                    matrix.set(tradeMtx, i + 1, 0, 2)
                    table.cell_set_bgcolor(tbl, 5, i + 1, bgcolor = #323232)
                    table.cell_set_bgcolor(tbl, 7, i + 1, bgcolor = #323232)
                    table.cell(tbl, 6, i + 1, 'Closed at TP\n' + str.tostring(tradeTp), bgcolor = #c8b50a, text_color = #000000, text_size = textSize)
                    tpSlMsg += 'Closed Buy' + '|' + symbol + '|' + timeframeText + '|' + entryTime + '|' + ' at TP\n'





            // plot the row
            table.cell(tbl, 0, i + 1, symbol + ' ' + timeframeText, text_halign = text.align_left, bgcolor = #dcc200, text_color = #000000, text_size = textSize)
            table.cell(tbl, 1, i + 1, '', bgcolor = fast_kernel)
            table.cell(tbl, 2, i + 1, '', bgcolor = slow_kernel)
            table.cell(tbl, 3, i + 1, '', bgcolor = kernel_ao)
            table.cell(tbl, 4, i + 1, '', bgcolor = range_shift)
            if matrix.get(tradeMtx, i + 1, 0) == 1 //if there is no trade in this row then colour it gray
                table.cell(tbl, 5, i + 1, '', bgcolor = #323232)
                table.cell(tbl, 6, i + 1, '', bgcolor = #323232)
                table.cell(tbl, 7, i + 1, '', bgcolor = #323232)
                




            isEntryOngoing := matrix.get(tradeMtx, i + 1, 0)
            closePrice = matrix.get(screenerMtx, i, 5)

            //this is to signal that there is no trade
            if isEntryOngoing == 1 or isEntryOngoing == 2
                
                // if there is a sell signal in this particular symbol & timeframe
                if fast_kernel_signal == 1 and slow_kernel_signal == 1 and (kernel_ao_bearish or range_shift_signal == 1)   
                    sl = matrix.get(screenerMtx, i, 6)
                    tp = closePrice > sl ? closePrice - ((closePrice-sl)*tpRatio) : closePrice - ((sl-closePrice)*tpRatio)
                    txt := txt + 'Sell' + '|' + str.tostring(closePrice) + '|' + str.tostring(tp) + '|' + str.tostring(sl) + '|' + symbol + '|' + timeframeText + '|' + entryTime + '\n'

                    table.cell(tbl, 5, i + 1, 'Sell \n'+str.tostring(closePrice), bgcolor = color.red, text_color = #000000, text_size = textSize)
                    table.cell(tbl, 6, i + 1, str.tostring(tp), bgcolor = color.red, text_color = #000000, text_size = textSize)
                    table.cell(tbl, 7, i + 1, str.tostring(sl), bgcolor = color.red, text_color = #000000, text_size = textSize)
                    matrix.set(tradeMtx, i + 1, 0, 0) //this is to signal that there is currently a trade open
                    matrix.set(tradeMtx, i + 1, 1, tp)
                    matrix.set(tradeMtx, i + 1, 2, sl)
                    matrix.set(tradeMtx, i + 1, 3, 1)
                    matrix.set(tradeMtx, i + 1, 4, counter) //assigning an identifier to this new trade
                    counter += 1


            
            if isEntryOngoing == 1  or isEntryOngoing == 2 //this is to signal that there is no trade 
                
                // if there is a buy signal in this particular symbol & timeframe
                if fast_kernel_signal == 0 and slow_kernel_signal == 0 and (kernel_ao_bullish or range_shift_signal == 0)  
                    sl = matrix.get(screenerMtx, i, 7)
                    tp = closePrice > sl ? closePrice + ((closePrice-sl)*tpRatio) : closePrice + ((sl-closePrice)*tpRatio)
                    txt := txt + 'Buy' + '|' + str.tostring(closePrice) + '|' + str.tostring(tp) + '|' + str.tostring(sl) + '|' + symbol + '|' + timeframeText + '|' + entryTime + '\n'

                    table.cell(tbl, 5, i + 1, 'Buy \n'+str.tostring(closePrice), bgcolor = color.green, text_color = #000000, text_size = textSize)
                    table.cell(tbl, 6, i + 1, str.tostring(tp), bgcolor = color.green, text_color = #000000, text_size = textSize)
                    table.cell(tbl, 7, i + 1, str.tostring(sl), bgcolor = color.green, text_color = #000000, text_size = textSize)
                    matrix.set(tradeMtx, i + 1, 0, 0) //this is to signal that there is currently a trade open
                    matrix.set(tradeMtx, i + 1, 1, tp)
                    matrix.set(tradeMtx, i + 1, 2, sl)
                    matrix.set(tradeMtx, i + 1, 3, 0)
                    matrix.set(tradeMtx, i + 1, 4, counter) //assigning an identifier to this new trade
                    counter += 1

            // changing the timeframe
            isLowerTF := isLowerTF ? false:true
                
        msg += txt
        msg += tpSlMsg
        
    if msg != ''
        alert(msg, alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. You cannot really make any noticable optimizations. Screeners are always slow because they use expensive functions like `security()` and drawings.

Answer (score 1):

dont use the _cleanArray() if you care about the number of the input
might need to adjust the screenerFun() if you do care but your doing alot of security request that are unneeded if you are toggling some off
you should be checking the flg before calling the security functions this will be faster
although there is still a ton you could do to speed this up i would suggest looking into user defined types(objects in pine)

```
s01 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's01') ?
      syminfo.ticker(input.symbol('EURUSD', group='Symbols', inline='s01')) : ""

s02 = input.bool(true,  title = "", group = 'Symbols', inline = 's02') ?
      syminfo.ticker(input.symbol('GBPUSD', group='Symbols', inline='s02')) : ""


tickerArray = array.from(s01, s02, ...)


_cleanArray() =>
    if tickerArray.size()
        for tickerArray.size()-1 to 0
            if tickerArray.get(i) == ""
                tickerArray.remove(i)


screenerFun(numSym, sym, tf) =>
    flg = sym != "" ? true : false
    if flg 
        [fastK, slowK, ao, rangeShift, prevClosePrice, swingHigh, swingLow, currClosePRice, currHigh, currLow] = request.security(sym, tf, screener_func()) 
        arr = array.from(numSym, fastK, slowK, ao, rangeShift, prevClosePrice, swingHigh, swingLow, currClosePRice, currHigh, currLow)
        matrix.add_row(screenerMtx, matrix.rows(screenerMtx), arr)


_screenerFunc() =>
    for i = 0 to array.size(tickerArray)-1
        screenerFun(i, tickerArray.get(i), lowerTF), 
        screenerFun(i, tickerArray.get(i), higherTF)

_cleanArray()
_screenerFunc()
```

you can also do things like this to help you read it better atleast i like it

```
    // GETTING THAT PARTICULAR SYMBOL'S DATA
    // indicator's signals
    fast_kernel_signal = matrix.get(screenerMtx, i, 1) 
    slow_kernel_signal = matrix.get(screenerMtx, i, 2) 
    kernel_ao_signal   = matrix.get(screenerMtx, i, 3)
    range_shift_signal = matrix.get(screenerMtx, i, 4)
    kernel_ao_bearish  = kernel_ao_signal == 2 or kernel_ao_signal == 3
    kernel_ao_bullish  = kernel_ao_signal == 0 or kernel_ao_signal == 1
```

these arnt in order or anything so you can fit them where they go but using the syminfo.ticker() around the input symbol should return it without an prefix so you can get rid of the id_symbol()

you can also remove the tftext() because it does nothing but throw an error if its not a string.. but if it wasnt a string it would throw an error anyway..

I didnt test this code but you seem do have enough of an understand of pinescript that any minor errors I made shouldnt be an issue more or less showing you what you could do than doing it for you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for your contribution. However, while I appreciate that English may not be your first language, your post - as it stands - is very hard to read. In many cases, I am happy to correct grammatical/spelling errors in posts by new users but, in this case, I don't have sufficient expertise in the subject to do so safely. I strongly suggest that you edit this answer to improve the language and readability.

Answer (score 0):

Tables are pretty intensive in their computational requirements.
That being true, I think the number one way you can increase efficiency is to create the table (using `table.new()` and `table.cell()`) to create the table on `barstate.isfirst`

At that point the table is created and no cell or table calls need to be made for the rest of the script. Then use the `table.set_cell_*()` functions to update and display values on the current bar.
Since historical values of the table are meaningless, it would make sense to put these updates inside of a `if barstate.islast` block. That should maximize your table efficiency.

Some things to note:

1. `barstate.islast = true` from the right-most bar at time of initialization and on every bar thereafter. Also, it does not become `false`  at any point in the future, even after the bar is no longer the last bar.
2. When you call `table.new()` on a bar it creates a table that exists on that bar. If, on the next bar, you call `table.new()` again, you place a new table overtop of the old one essentially, which hides it, but doesn't remove it. What this means is that you're wasting resources by layering tables on top of each other.
3. The same is true for `table.cell()`. When it is used you overwrite the cell that was there if there was one there, but it doesn't get rid of it.

So in 20,000 bars, you can really end up with quite the bloated script. If you have other complexities in the script you'll quickly run into memory and token errors.
Lastly, labels are harder to assemble, but much cheaper and don't hang out on the chart when not in view. The trouble with labels is attempting to anchor them in a way that is easy on the eyes.